# Unloading swfs loaded with Loader::load()

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, loader

I'm using `Loader::load()`  successfully to load swfs into my main swf and then I add them as a child of a Sprite.  When other events occur I want to remove the swfs as needed.  I have looked at `unload()` and at `removeChildAt()` without success.

I only added the `addChild()` call to try to pin down the loaded instance so I could remove it.  The loading works fine without the `addChild();`

I have also tried publishing to player v.10 and using `myLoader.unloadAndStop()`; but this has no effect either;

The following demo code shows my problem.  I see one child added and one removed but intro.swf is still playing away.

```
import flash.display.Loader; 
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.LoaderInfo;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();
var holderMC:Sprite = new Sprite();
var myRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest('intro.swf');

myLoader.load(myRequest);
holderMC.addChild(myLoader);
trace("initial:"+holderMC.numChildren);  // traces initial:1

while(holderMC.numChildren > 0) {
 holderMC.removeChildAt(0);
 trace("now there are:"+holderMC.numChildren); // traces now there are :0
}
myLoader.unload();
```

// **Edit**- also tried:

```
myLoader.unloadAndStop();
myLoader = null;
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You definitely have something else going on here.  First, how are you seeing the "intro.swf"?  You are creating holderMC, and adding the loaded swf as a child, but when are you adding holderMC to the display list?

The proper way to remove a movie from the view would be:

```
holderMC.removeChild(myLoader);
```

In order to let the content of holderMC to be flagged for garbage collection you need to set it to null. So,

```
holderMC.removeChild(myLoader);
myLoader.unload(); // this will set the content (the movie itself) to null.
myLoader = null; // npw the loader can be garbage collected too
```

If you are doing a removeChild and it is still showing, then you will need to post more code to show where the problem really is.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  I *think* the problem lay in the fact that I was converting an old AS2 file to AS3 and when I started with a fresh file and used your advice the problem resolved.  Thanks!